# Gulp watch - not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have gulpfile.js from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.
I just change folders name for mine. 
Task 'gulp' work normally, first 'gulp watch' too. But any another save any less file don't do anything. Just "Finished 'styles' after 1.34 s"
(JS works good)

Any advice?
main.less have less imports with all filles
Folders looks like:

```
/www
    /js
    /css
        main.less
        file.less
        file2.less
        /lib
            file3.less




var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var del = require('del');

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'www/css/main.less',
        dest: 'www/css/'
    },
    scripts: {
        src: 'www/js/js/**/*.js',
        dest: 'www/js/'
    }
};

function clean() {
  return del([ 'assets' ]);
}

function styles() {
  return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    // pass in options to the stream
    .pipe(rename({
      basename: 'main',
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

function scripts() {
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts.src, { sourcemaps: true})
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch("www/js/js**/*.js", scripts);
  gulp.watch("www/css/**/*.less", styles);
}

exports.clean = clean;
exports.styles = styles;
exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.watch = watch;

var build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(styles, scripts));

gulp.task('build', build);

gulp.task('default', build);
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing `/` in `www/js/js**/*.js`?

Comment: There is no problem with javascript, i have problem only with LESS

Comment: I mean, yes. '/' was missing, but nothing change when i add it

Comment: I think `watch()` is never being executed. Try adding `gulp.task('watch', watch);` and invoke `gulp watch` afterwards. Just a guess.

Comment: Nothing change :/ but thx for try

Answer (score 0):

As @Jakub thought, you never actually call your watch task in the code you presented!  You probably want something like this:

```
var build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(styles, scripts), watch);
```